# Windows 2008 R2 Not resolving IP's or domains

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ip, domains, resolve

I have two servers with Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, and today I realized that one of them don't resolve IP's or domain names.

If I ping the same machine IP, it respond, but if I ping an external IP (like 8.8.8.8 or any other) it does not work. The same with domain names.

At Windows Event Viewer I'm having Warning 1014: Name resolution for the name  timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded

THE SERVER HAS CONNECTIVITY, I'm connected remotely and the services and incoming traffic (like FTP, etc) are working OK.

Things I've done & tested:

- Run Kaspersky Virus Removal 10
- Restart/Turn off the DNS Client service
- Clean the hosts file
- Reboot the server
- Turn off the Windows Firewall (there's not another firewall)
- Quit or replace the current DNS servers

I just can ping the same machine IP or the gateway!

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are the DNS settings of the machine correct?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's nothing to do with DNS or domain names - if you can't ping an IP then you're looking at a connectivity problem. The reason it won't resolve domain names is almost certainly because it can't speak to its DNS server.

Can it ping another machine on the same subnet? How about one you know is plugged into the same switch? The fact that you can ping the default gateway says mis-configured network or Access Control List to me, though it's very hard to say.

What's the exact result when you ping 8.8.8.8?

Do your other servers definitely get a response to ping to the same IP's you're trying? It's possible that ICMP is blocked and that's a red herring. You could try manually browsing to a website using its IP (Ping one on your own machine to return an IP) to see what happens.

Comment: Hi, all machines have only public IP, so I can't ping another machine as LAN. When I ping 8.8.8.8:Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.